# Como verificar se um arquivo existe por numeragem

Tags: python-3.x

Queria poder fazer um cadastro de usuarios em sequencia numeral crescente (1,2,3,4)
mas eu queria saber algum jeito de saber se o usuario ja existe e tentar com um numero maior

Exemplo:
Tente criar um arquivo 1 - Eduardo.txt
se ja existir um arquivo de codigo 1
tentar com 2 e assim em diante

Tentei fazer isso e não funcionou

```
import os.path

def verifica(x):
    certeza = os.path.exists("C:\Users\danie\Desktop\saida\{}.txt".format(x))
    if certeza == True:
        x += 1
enc = 'UTF-8'
decisao = str(input("Quer criar um novo usuario?"))
if decisao == 'sim':
    x = 0
    verifica(x)
    arquivo = open(r'C:\Users\danie\Desktop\saida\{}.txt'.format(x), 'w', encoding=enc)
    arquivo.write('Teste de texto')
    arquivo.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema no seu código é que você não repete a verificação para achar um arquivo X que não exista no diretório. Dentro da sua função `verifica()` por exemplo, você incrementa a variável `x` caso o arquivo já exista, porém você não chama novamente a função.

Para resolver o problema você pode criar um bloco de repetição ou então utilizar da recursividade para repetir a verificação quantas vezes forem necessárias. Veja abaixo alguns exemplos:

**Utilizando recursividade:**

```
import os

def verifica(arquivo, x = 0):

    if os.path.exists(arquivo.format(x)):
        return verifica( arquivo, x + 1 )
    else:
        # Ao invés de retornar só o número, ele já retorna
        # o nome de arquivo formatado.
        return arquivo.format(x) 

enc = 'UTF-8'

# A função input já retorna por padrão uma string, então não é necessário
# converter o dado obtido para str().
decisao = input("Quer criar um novo usuario? ").lower()

# Verifica se a decisão começa com a letra "s".
if decisao.startswith('s'):

    nome_de_arquivo = verifica(r"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\saida\{}.txt")

    arquivo = open(nome_de_arquivo, 'w', encoding = enc)
    arquivo.write('Teste de texto')
    arquivo.close()
```

**Utilizando bloco de repetição:**

```
# Como estamos utilizando um bloco de repetição, não é necessário criar a função verifica().
if decisao.startswith('s'):

    x = 0
    nome_de_arquivo = r"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\saida\{}.txt"

    while True:
        if os.path.exists(nome_de_arquivo.format(x)):
            x += 1
        else:
            break

    arquivo = open(nome_de_arquivo.format(x), 'w', encoding=enc)
    arquivo.write('Teste de texto')
    arquivo.close()
```

Se você quiser também limitar a quantidade de X arquivos no seu diretório, basta substituir o bloco `while` por um `for..range(limite)` dessa forma:

```
if decisao.startswith('s'):

    limite = 1000  # Limite de 1000 arquivos
    nome_de_arquivo = r"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\saida\{}.txt"
    x_arquivo = None

    for x in range(limite)
        if not os.path.exists(nome_de_arquivo.format(x)):
            x_arquivo = x

    if x_arquivo:
        arquivo = open(nome_de_arquivo.format(x), 'w', encoding=enc)
        arquivo.write('Teste de texto')
        arquivo.close()
    else:
        print("ULTRAPASSOU O LIMITE!")
```